# Error in checking rails version on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, version

I installed ruby and rails on my ubuntu 10.04 system.While checking rails version it gave me error like this below.

```
$ rails -v
getopt: invalid option -- 'v'
Terminating...
```

What is wrong with the rails?Thanks in advance.
I installed rails using gem.
I followed the instructions from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

Comment: how did you install rails? (through bundler or gem install). and ruby? are you using rvm o rbenv? Please provide as much relevant information as you can.

Comment: Does `rails --help` work?

Comment: And the gem version i installed is the latest version 2.2.2 but sunil had mentioned 2.3.x.Actually it doesnot exist.

Answer (score 0):

check this link http://community.activestate.com/faq/running-rails-debian

Turns out rails -v only works in version 2.3.x and upwards. I suspect you have an older version that is being used even while a newer gem is available, which is what was happening in my system.

To solve I deleted the following:
usr/share/rails
usr/bin/rails - this is the generator script that keeps screwing up

Uninstall Rails with 'sudo gem uninstall rails' and reinstall again.

That solved my problem.

Warning it might break your system and possibly cause weather change patterns in or around Southeast Asia. Don't say I didn't warn you.